addLocatorHandler() does not seem to work with iframes
I am trying to use the addLocatorHandler() but the overlay I am trying to handle is part of an iframe and it does not seem to work with iframes.
The error i get with the code below is "Property 'addLocatorHandler' does not exist on type 'FrameLocator'."
const toolIframe = await (await page.waitForSelector('iframe[name*="tool_content"]')).contentFrame();

const iframe = await toolIframe.frameLocator('#main-content iframe');

await iframe.addLocatorHandler(iframe.getByText('Sign In'), async () => {
    await iframe.getByText('Close').click();
});


Thanks, but do you have a sample page or HTML snippet this is running on? Locators don't need to be awaited. toolIframe is already the frame so you don't need to locate it, or use the frame locator rather than waitForSelector()/contentFrame().
